# One of two identical projects raises 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have to identical projects on DigitalOcean. Both are on different droplets (created by one click install Django).

One of them works correctly but the second one returns `502 Bad Gateway`.

I've checked and corrected everything I know about.

1. Installed the same requiremets
2. Checked for identical `manage.py`, `wsgi.py` and `settings.py` files.
3. Set identical `etc/nginx/sites-available/django` and `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`
4. Tried to set equal permissions - this is from WinScp of both projects:

**The first project doesn't work and the second works correctly.**

**Main dirs:**

[image]

**Project dirs:**

[image]

The only difference is on the second picture. The upper line has different permissions.

Of course I've restarted both **NGINX** and **gunicorn**.

Do you know what's the problem or at least what I didn't checked?

In case it helps I'm attaching a part of `var/log/nginx/errors.log` and `var/upstart/gunicorn.log`

**NGINX**

```
2016/08/20 05:29:22 [error] 9084#0: *433 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.101.102.108, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/"
2016/08/20 05:29:53 [error] 9084#0: *435 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "192.81.222.38"
2016/08/20 05:29:53 [error] 9084#0: *435 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico", host: "192.81.222.38", referrer: "http://192.81.222.38/"
2016/08/20 05:39:22 [error] 9084#0: *440 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.101.102.108, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/"
2016/08/20 05:43:19 [notice] 18323#0: signal process started
2016/08/20 05:43:36 [error] 18324#0: *444 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "192.81.222.38"
2016/08/20 05:43:36 [error] 18324#0: *444 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico", host: "192.81.222.38", referrer: "http://192.81.222.38/"
2016/08/20 05:49:22 [error] 18324#0: *448 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 5.101.102.108, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/"
2016/08/20 05:51:04 [error] 18324#0: *450 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "192.81.222.38"
2016/08/20 05:51:05 [error] 18324#0: *450 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico", host: "192.81.222.38", referrer: "http://192.81.222.38/"
```

**gunicorn**

```
ImportError: No module named drevo.wsgi
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19089] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19089)
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19090] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19090
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19090] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named drevo.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named drevo.wsgi
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19090] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19090)
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19091] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19091
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19091] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named drevo.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named drevo.wsgi
2016-08-20 05:44:19 [19091] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19091)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==17.5', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 42, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE").run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 144, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 196, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 291, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 334, in stop
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 430, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Comment: Missing the `x` privilege off of a directory is probably a fatal difference.

Comment: I'm new in this area, could you post an answer me how to set the privilege? Thanks

Comment: Usually the `chmod` command - I don't know how you do it on a DigitalOcean droplet though.

Comment: Try to add `/home/django/drevo` to `PYTHONPATH`